# How to Generate Random Damage Points for Game? - Java

Tags: java, random

I'm building a mini game in which two monsters battle each other (an opponent and the player). When the round starts, the monsters are supposed to fight and their health points decrease by 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

I'm using *Math.random* to randomize the damage dealt to each of the monsters.

How do I decrease each monster's health points when the program is run and the round starts?

Here is my code so far (*Monster.java* file):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Monster {
    // Monster properties
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private int damage;

    // Random damage points that vary from 1 to 5
    int randomDamagePoints = (int)(Math.random() * 1 + 5);

    // Constructor
    public Monster(String name, int health, int damage) {
        this.name = "Monster";
        this.health = 50;
        this.damage = 2;
    }

    // Opponent attacks Monster 1 - Player
    public void AttackPlayer(Monster player) {
        while(health > 0) {
            // Part I need help with
        }
    }

    // Player attacks Monster 2 - Opponent
    public void AttackOpponent(Monster opponent) {
        while(health > 0) {
            // Part I need help with
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the issue?  Put `int randomDamagePoints = (int)(Math.random() * 1 + 5);` in the function `AttackOpponent` and return the calculated value and subtract it from health or something.

Comment: Also you are not actually using their `damage` stat right now.  What you could do for example is generate a random value such as 1 to 5 then multiply it by their damage so you can adjust the strength of a Monster.  It might be useful to use higher numbers to not have such an exponential increase in strength from `1` to `3` for example (or decimals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to determine who would win when in both cases they would be dealing damage to each other between 1 and 5.

To do this you can use something like this:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Monster {
  // Monster properties
  private String name;
  public int health; //public so that Monsters hitting each other can manipulate health.
  private int damage;

  public int getRandomDamage() {
    return (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  }

  public void Fight(Monster opponent) {
    while (this.health > 0 && opponent.health > 0) {
      opponent.health -= this.getRandomDamage();
      this.health -= opponent.getRandomDamage();
    }
    if (opponent.health>this.health) {
      System.out.println(this.name + " lost!");
    } else {
      System.out.println(opponent.name + " lost!");
    }
  } 

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer! This worked for me as well; I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, your about your damage formula:

```
int randomDamagePoints = (int)(Math.random() * 1 + 5);
```

This is going to always result in 5. You want

```
int randomDamagePoints = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
```

If you want the damage to change round to round, you should put this in its own function or in the attack function. Also, I'd recommend that you only have one `attack` function, call it `attackMe`, with a damage parameter. Then just subtract damage from hit points, something like

```
public boolean attackMe(int damage) {
  health -= damage;
  return hitPoints > 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for correcting my damage formula! I appreciate it. +1